# Perl - DBI - How to process array rather than single value?

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

I have code running a SQL query `select rec_data from foo where id=?`, and I do something with the return value.

I now have an array of IDs `@queryIDs;`, how can I run the same query and gather the results in order for the values in this array? Thanks

Comment: How about perl `foreach` or sql `where id in (..)`?

Comment: @mpapec I have an array of values I want to run the query for, and build up an array of results, is a foreach the best way to do this? for where id in can I pass an array and get an array of responses?

Comment: [Crossposted](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1081791)

Comment: @choroba I was told it was off topic. I won't be back at that site

Comment: @user3318259 update question with your existing fetching code

Comment: @user3318259: Sure, one ugly user means the whole site sucks.

Comment: Just keep in mind that it's easier to help if there is enough information in your question. Please [edit] the question and show the Perl code you have already written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
my $sql = 'select rec_data from foo where id in (';
$sql .= join ',', ("?") x @queryIDs;
$sql .= ') order by id';

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$sth-> execute(@queryIDs);

# rest of code will be the same as you have now
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is insecure.

To do the same securely, split the list in SQL, which depends on the RDBMS and version. For example, Oracle 11r2 has a good tokenization method via XMLDB which can be found with a simple search, or the MODEL clause, for those ot scared to use it. SQL Server also does XML. Without the RDBMS and version, it is hard to suggest what to do.

Comment: What is insecure about Dave Cross's solution using placeholders?

Comment: It is no more insecure than any dynamic SQL. Indeed, building placeholders dynamically is a much better course than actually building it dynamically, although less efficient.

Comment: Again, what exactly is insecure about it?

Comment: I think you are asking what is insecure about dynamic SQL when all options seem to be covered. The answer to that is that while theoretically secure, we often miss options, and new options can be added to the database. A good example of that is fields that use NLS parameters in Oracle, where a user can change the value of the NLS variable in his own session and change the meaning of the statement. The only way to guarantee secure SQL (when accepting parameters) is to use bind variables and have the statement in the database itself.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks for the explanation. I'm not sure why your answer was downvoted, but perhaps an example would be in order (using the RDBMS of your choice).

Comment: I didn't give an example because i am still learning it, and there are many ways, and it changes by RDBMS. Here's an example for Oracle, using XMLDB and ora:tokenize (requires version 11.2), which i grabbed from https://community.oracle.com/thread/2444487?start=15&tstart=0:    SELECT b.str  
      FROM (SELECT 'a,b,c,d,e' str FROM DUAL) t,  
           XMLTABLE ('ora:tokenize($v, ",")'  
                     PASSING str AS "v"  
                     COLUMNS str VARCHAR2 (80) PATH '.') b